# What is the current status of GHC on 64 bit Windows?

Tags: haskell, 64-bit

My current understanding is

- No 64-bit GHC, ticket [#1884](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1884)
- The 32-bit GHC and the binaries it builds work just fine because the Windows OS loader converts OS calls and pointers to 64 bits.  <strike>The same applies to DLLs</strike>
- No mixing 32 bit and 64 bit code (ie. your 32 bit Haskell DLL isn't going to be friends with the 64 bit program that wants to use it)
- Latest discussion is a thread started on [May 2011](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-May/092021.html)

Is this correct?  Are there any pitfalls to watch out for, particularly as an FFI user?  For example, if I were to export some Haskell code as a 32 bit DLL to some Windows program, should I expect it to work?

**Edit**: looks like you'd need a 64 bit DLL to go with a 64 bit process

Comment: This is probably something where directly asking on the mailing list is likely to be faster...

Comment: Thanks! Was sort of hoping that this would end up being a more wiki-like resource that could evolve with time, where current == 20xx.  My first SO question :-)

Comment: SO questions tend to end up quiet after being answered, unfortunately :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anyone's actively working on a 64-bit codegen right now, but 32-bit haskell will work just fine as long as you're only talking to 32-bit FFI libraries (and/or being embedded in 32-bit host programs). If you want to interact with 64-bit programs, you will need to use some form of IPC, as 32-bit and 64-bit code cannot coexist in one process.

Answer (score 0):

64-bit windows is supported now. There is binary a distribution of 64-bit GHC.

No 64-bit Haskell Platform yet though.